# The ring $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a domain

Tags: ring-theory

True\False :The ring $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a domain

solution

True 
A commutative ring with identity is said to be
an integral domain if it has no zero divisors.

Comment: What is (0,1)(1,0)?

Comment: $(\bar{1}, \bar{0})(\bar{0},\bar{1}) = (\bar{0}, \bar{0})$. So the ring does have zero-divisors. In fact, an integral domain cannot have a decomposition as $R \times S$, where $R$ and $S$ are non-zero!